# Lifecycle Testing with Robotium: Killing and Restarting Activity

Tags: java, android, robotium, android-testing

**How is it possible to restart an activity that was ended using Robotium's `solo.goBack()`?**

The following does not restart the activity: (the test finishes ok)

```
    solo.goBack();
    try {
    //  recreate activity here
    runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnCreate(getActivity(), 
                              null);
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStart(getActivity());
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(getActivity());
        }});
    }
```

How do you restart an Activity that was ended by `Solo.goBack()`?

#### SO-questions

- [Testing activity flow with robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235086/testing-activity-flow-with-robotium)
  addresses changing between two activities in Robotium, not destoying and restarting.
- [Simulate Android killing and restart service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435456/simulate-android-killing-and-restart-service)
  deals with a service, not an activity (and is unanswered)
- [Activity doesn't restart in different tests with Robotium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608353/activity-doesnt-restart-in-different-tests-with-robotium)
  asks how to restart the activity manually, but is answered in a different way

#### Minimal example

To reproduce a minimal test like this, create a project and its test project:

```
android create project -t 1 -p testRestart -k com.testRestart -a testactivity
cd testRestart
mkdir tests
cd tests
android create test-project -m .. -p .
```

Copy the [Robotium jar](http://dl.bintray.com/robotium/generic/robotium-solo-5.3.1.jar) to the `tests/libs` folder.
Paste this code inside the file `testactivityTest.java`:

```
package com.testRestart;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class testactivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<testactivity> {
    private Solo solo;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }

    public testactivityTest() {
        super("com.testRestart", testactivity.class);

    }

    public void testDestroyAndRestart() {
        solo.goBack();
    try {
        //  recreate activity here
        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            getInstrumentation().callActivityOnCreate(getActivity(), 
                                  null);
            getInstrumentation().callActivityOnStart(getActivity());
            getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(getActivity());
            }});
    } catch ( Throwable t ) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
    }
}
```

Inside the tests folder, do a

```
ant debug install
adb shell am instrument -w -e class com.testRestart.testactivityTest com.testRestart.tests/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

The question again: how can you restart an activity that was ended by `Solo.goBack()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @IHeartAndroid said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673580/1587329) to [this robotium question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644288/how-to-relaunch-the-closed-app-in-robotium/17744154#17744154) (I had not seen it before, there was a link by @Flavio Capaccio in a comment to a "[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802233/how-to-restart-killed-android-application-in-testing-with-robotium?rq=1)"):

```
launchActivity("com.testRestart", testactivity.class, null);
```

works. This is a function in [InstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html).

(If you want to upvote this answer, upvote [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11673580/1587329) as well)